# wordcound configuration invalid escape character

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm trying to configure the [wordcount pluging for sublimetext](https://github.com/titoBouzout/WordCount) to exclude everything in square brakets.
My goal is to count the words in a snippet like this:

```
My name is Frank [p. 12].
```

Sublimetext counts this as 6 words. I want it to be 4.
I used the find by regex function with `\[.*\]` and it highlights the right portion of the text.
However, when editing the user settings to include the `"cit"` part like this

```
    "strip": {
    "php": [
        "<[^>]*>"
    ],
    "html": [
        "<[^>]*>"
    ],
    "cit":[
        "\[.*\]"
    }
```

I get the error **"Error trying to parse settings: Invalid escape in ... WordCount.sublime-settings"**

What other escape character can I use? If I escape it using two backslashes `\\` the wordcount stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks fine. The reason you're getting the error is because there is no closing `]` **after** the regex:

```js
"strip": {
"php": [
    "<[^>]*>"
],
"html": [
    "<[^>]*>"
],
"cit":[ // not matched
    "\[.*\]"
}
```

Change it to this:

```js
"strip": {
    "php": [
        "<[^>]*>"
    ],
    "html": [
        "<[^>]*>"
    ],
    "cit": [ 
        "\[.*\]"
    ]
}
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you, I see how that is an error. But even after correcting the missing brackets the error message remains the same when trying to save the configuration.